# python urllib2 urlopen response

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

python urllib2 urlopen response:

```
<addinfourl at 1081306700 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x4073192c>>
```

expected:

{"token":"mYWmzpunvasAT795niiR"}

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to bind the resultant file-like object to a variable, otherwise the interpreter just dumps it via `repr`:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
<addinfourl at 18362520 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x106b250>>
>>> 
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
>>> f
<addinfourl at 18635448 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x106b950>>
```

To get the actual data you need to perform a `read()`.

```
>>> data = f.read()
>>> data[:50]
'<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtyp'
```

To see the headers returned:

```
>>> print f.headers
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2012 00:46:22 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
... etc ...
```

Comment: I have one question here. If I don't store the contents of `f` to `data`, and simply perform `f.read()`, I get the contents only once. If I do `f.read()` again, it prints an empty string. Why is that?

Comment: @SidharthSamant: because you have consumed all of the data from the stream - it is not stored internally by `urllib2`.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following after your call to `urlopen`

```
print feed.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will find using the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org) more intuitive to use than `urllib2`.