# python urllib2 random website hyperlink accessing

Tags: python, hyperlink, urllib2

I would like to make python script that will randomly access hyperlinks on some website on every 1 second.

Started with validating url:

```
def valid_url(url):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False

print valid_url('www.python.org')
```

1. I can get hyperlink using re

> ```
> import urllib2
> import re
> url = 'http://www.python.org/'
> page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
> page = page.read()
> links = re.findall(r"<a.*?\s*href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)</a>", page)
> for link in links:
>     print('href: %s, HTML text: %s' % (link[0], link[1]))
> ```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: please give more information what you have tried so far

Comment: Started with validating url:

def valid_url(url):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        return False

print valid_url('www.python.org')

Comment: Edit the question and add it there..

Comment: thanks. im kinda new to stuckoverflow...

Comment: IMO this question seems to make some sense, but it is quite vague. Please add more details on what you intend to do exactly.

Comment: OK @aadlv, what else do you want? You pretty much got it all and just need to wrap it to make it happend..

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
print valid_url('http://www.python.org')
```

You can see how to handle it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083231/python-urllib2-urlopen-response).

If you want to access random hyperlinks you will have to parse the page in order to collect the urls, use random choise every second (with a loop that uses time.sleep(1)) and use the urlopen to access.

If you'll give more information, I will able to assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

So.. This is the script i wanted:

```
import urllib2
import re
from random import randrange
import time

url = 'http://some web site...'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = page.read()
links = re.findall(r"<a.*?\s*href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)</a>", page)

while True:
    i = randrange(len(links))
    if not links[i][0].startswith('http'):
        n = urllib2.urlopen(url + links[i][0])
        open_url = n.read
        close_url = n.close
        # n.geturl()
        print 'Opened ' + url + links[i][0]
        time.sleep(5)
```